# Can not show external HDD during photorec

Tags: external-hdd, testdisk, photorec

I have just formated my HP laptop (having **500 GB** Hard Disk **Internal**) and install Ubuntu 14.04 LTS OS. while get back up for lost files, I install **testdisk** and run **sudo photorec**. All process is going **fine**, but I want to save the **resotred** documents, photos , videos etc in my  1 TB **External** Seagate HDD (SATA) . But there is no option for my **External** HDD in **photorec** window.
How can I do so.

[image]

Comment: Do I understand you correctly that you want to recover files from the internal drive you just installed Ubuntu on? Or do you mean a third drive not mentioned in your question?

Comment: Btw. what's the HP icon in your panel? Just asking out of interest, unrelated to your problem?

Comment: @the_Seppi HP Linux Imaging and Printing `sudo apt-get install hplip-gui`

Comment: Why all the bold?

Answer (score 5):

The USB drive probably was mounted in `/media/bapi/<name_of_drive`. We can browse to the root directory (`/`) with selecting `..` twice then select `media`, `bapi`, `<name>`.

If it is not present there try mounting from Nautilus to be able to write on that drive.

For a guide to access and recover files on a system drive from an Ubuntu live session see

- [How do I recover my accidentally lost Windows partitions after installing Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/286181/how-do-i-recover-my-accidentally-lost-windows-partitions-after-installing-ubuntu)

Comment: still the problem is same.

Comment: @BapiSaha: also see link I gave in the edit. Can you "see" your external drive from Nautilus (aka "Files")?